# Undefined variable: id when trying to pass data from URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables, undefined

I am trying to pass variable.
I want to show all the sponsor ids from the id. i.e. if 203035051 passed in the URL then in the view i can see all ids for which 203035051 is sponsor.

[image]

**Here is my anchor link:**

```html
<a href="<?=base_url('v3/member_income?id='.$id);?>">
```

**Here is my Model: MemberIncome**

```html
public function display_records($id)
        {
                $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where("id",$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query) {
             return $query->row_array();
         } else {
             return false;
         }
        }
```

**Here is my Controller**

```html
public function displaydata()
    {
        /*load Model*/
        $this->load->model('MemberIncome');
    $result['data']=$this->MemberIncome->display_records($id);
    $this->load->view('customer/member_income', $result);
    }
```

**here is my route**

```html
$route['v3/member_income'] = 'IncomeData/displaydata';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the reason:

```
$route['v3/member_income'] = 'IncomeData/displaydata';
```

You need to send the ID through routes. Add the (:any) and $1 those are the parameters you need to send. Without it, the "displaydata" won't receive the ID.

```
$route['v3/member_income/(:any)'] = 'IncomeData/displaydata/$1';
```

In the anchor section, actually you don't need "?id=", just send it like this

```
<a href="<?= base_url('v3/member_income/'.$id); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing something in route to catch your ID. Try this way

```
$route['v3/member_income/(:any)'] = 'IncomeData/displaydata/$1';
```